# iText 7 : How to position "page x of y" to the bottom right

Tags: java, events, itext, position, itext7

Using itext 7, I followed Page X of Y tutorial here - https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-7-handling-events-setting-viewer-preferences-and-printer-properties#Chapter7:Handlingevents;settingviewerpreferencesandprinterproperties-Solvingthe%22PageXofY%22problem
Our requirement is to put page number to the bottom right. I tried variations of x, y position for the placeholder and initial "Page x of", but it isn't getting positioned correctly. And If the total number of pages 3 digits, it overlaps "of". If the total number of pages is 2 digit - there is a space between "of" and total. How do I position it in order to not have additional spaces or overlapping characters.
Here is the code -

```
...
...
float topMargin = 30;
float bottomMargin = topMargin + 20;
float rightMargin = topMargin;
float leftMargin = topMargin;
Document document = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);      
document.setMargins(topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin, leftMargin);
...
..
PageXofY pageXofYEvent = new PageXofY(pdf, document);
pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, pageXofYEvent);
pageXofYEvent.writeTotal(pdf);


public class PageXofY implements IEventHandler
{
  protected PdfFormXObject placeholder;
  PdfFont font = ITextFonts.getWriterBaseFont();
  

  protected float side = 20;
  protected float x = 300;
  protected float y = 30;
  protected float space = 10f;
  protected float descent = 3;
  Document document;
  float pWidth = 0;

  public PageXofY(PdfDocument pdf, Document document)
  {
    placeholder = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(-20, -15, 100, 100));
    this.document = document;
  }

  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event)
  {    
    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
    PdfDocument pdf = docEvent.getDocument();
    PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();
    int pageNumber = pdf.getPageNumber(page);
    
    Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.getLastContentStream(), page.getResources(), pdf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, pageSize);
    
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("Page ").add(String.valueOf(pageNumber)).add(" of ")
        .setFont(font).setFontSize(8).setMarginTop(10f);
    pWidth = TableColumnSpacer.getParagraphWidth(p, document);      
    x = pageSize.getRight() - document.getRightMargin() - pWidth - 4f;
    y = pageSize.getBottom() + 30 ;//document.getBottomMargin();            
    canvas.showTextAligned(p, x, y, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);    
    pdfCanvas.addXObjectAt(placeholder, x - space , y - 18);
    pdfCanvas.release();
  }

  public void writeTotal(PdfDocument pdf)
  {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholder, pdf);
          
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(String.valueOf(pdf.getNumberOfPages())).setFont(font).setFontSize(8).setMarginTop(10f); 
    canvas.showTextAligned(p, 30, descent, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding "page x of y" in events only makes sense if you know in advance how much space approximately is required for the total pages. If you don't know, you should create the pdf without "page x of y" in a first run and stamp the page numbers in a second run when you know the total.

Comment: hello mkl, By space, do you mean If we know what will be the total (either 2 digit or 4 diigit num) in advance ? Also, can you explain and give an example on how stamp the page numbers in second run.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your response. Yes, that's what i meant, and your answer is what i had in mind concerning a second run solution.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue by adding page footer once the whole document is generated. Iterating over the pages and adding footer text and page x of y. Here is the code -

```
public void stampPageFooter(Document doc, String name) throws Exception 
  {
    int numberOfPages = doc.getPdfDocument().getNumberOfPages();
    PdfDocument pdfDocument =  doc.getPdfDocument();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) 
    {
       PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(i);
       Rectangle pageSize = page.getPageSize();
       float pageX = pageSize.getRight() - doc.getRightMargin() - 40;
       float pageY = pageSize.getBottom() + 30 ;       
        // Write x of y to the right bottom
       Paragraph p = new Paragraph(String.format("Page %s of %s", i, numberOfPages)).addStyle(PAGE_NUM_STYLE);
       doc.showTextAligned(p, pageX, pageY, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
       // write name to the left
       pageX = pageSize.getLeft() + doc.getLeftMargin();
       pageY = pageSize.getBottom() + 30;
       Paragraph para = new Paragraph(name).addStyle(PAGE_NUM_STYLE).setMarginTop(10f);
       doc.showTextAligned(para, pageX, pageY ,  i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
   
    }
```